# regex match string followed by any word followed by string variable

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a predefined variable called probe_name, it is the 3rd word in the string. In the below example it will could be name1, name2 and name3

```
list1 = [ 
probe url name1 
probe http name1 
probe tcp name2 
probe http name3 
abc 123 xyz1 
www 123 xyz2 ]
```

How would I match the lines that match the probe_name value in the list I have above?

I want to first match the word "probe" and then need the regex to match any string of characters to follow and then need to match the last word as my probe_value.

ex:

```
probe_name = [name1] 
for line in list1: 
if ("probe " "regex to match any second word " + probe_name) in line:
```

what regex can I use to say match any string of characters as the 2nd word?

I thought this would have worked but it doesn't:

```
if ("probe .* $" + probe_name) in line:
```

Comment: Can you reformulate `list1` to be a valid Python expression?  As it is, it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.*` means `any character except \n (0 or more times)`

or

`.+` means `any character except \n (1 or more times)`

Example:

```
if re.match("probe .*"+prob_name, line):
   # do something
```

Make sure the `prob_name` doesn't have any special regex character like `.` `*` `(` etc